# Resizing AWS Redshift cluster, does each node need an IP?

Tags: resize, amazon-redshift

I once resized my aws Redshift cluster and it was resized from 1 node to 4 nodes just fine, but now that I again need to resize it, after applying the modifications to increase nodes from 4 to 5, the status of cluster changes to `resizing`, and then back to `available` but number of nodes are still the same.

One thing I have noticed is there is no more available IP addresses in the subnet I have created the cluster, can that be an issue? does each node need an separate IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Amazon Redshift node is effectively an EC2 instance in your VPC (it doesn't appear in the the EC2 console, but it uses one).

Therefore, yes, you will require IP addresses to be available in your subnets. If you are resizing from 4 to 5 nodes, you would need 5 IP addresses for all the new nodes during the resize process.

If your subnet has no available IP addresses, you will need to use another subnet. Check the contents of your [Cluster Subnet Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-cluster-subnet-groups.html) so that it knows where to launch the cluster. I'm not sure if a resize will work across AZs/Subnets, but give it a try!